# How to make the message/label to be closed

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I need your help or some pointers on my challenge.

In my web application, I am displaying a warning message and a dashboard to the user.

The message is a label that tells some information about the dashboard. I am playing the dashboard in browser frame.

Please refer to the code below,

```
Label warningMessage = new Label("Warning : Dashboard is only accessible under local network/VPN.");
BrowserFrame boxInfo = new BrowserFrame(null, new ExternalResource(address));
boxInfo.setSizeFull();
VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.addComponent(warningMessage);
layout.addComponent(boxInfo);
layout.setExpandRatio(warningMessage, 0);
layout.setExpandRatio(boxInfo, 1);
layout.setSizeFull();
body.addComponent(layout);
body.setSizeFull();
```

My requirement as follows,

The label or any other component that display the message, should have a privilege to be closed as soon as the user clicks "X" button on the label.

It should be like

***Warning : Dashboard is only accessible under local network/VPN.                            X***

When the user reads the message and clicks on the "X" button/whatever it is. The message should disappear and browser frame  needs to be re-sized to occupy the space of the label/component.

Please advice how to do this.

Comment: Wrap your label and the "X"-Button in a new layout and hide/remove it when clicking the button.

Comment: This might be helpful for you in general: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-settings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would most likely create a new server-side component for it.

pseudocode below.

```
class ClosableLabel extends HorizontalLayout { 
  public CloseableLabel(String label, Button.ClickListener listener){
    addComponent(new Label(label));
    addComponent(new Button("x", listener);
  }

  // Probably needs some setters and such
}
```

In the view, you can then use these:

```
CloseableLabel label = new CloseableLabel("Warning : Dashboard is only accessible under local network/VPN.", new ClickListener {
  @Override
  public onClick(event){ //or what ever the implementable method of ClickListener is called.
    layout.removeComponent(label);
  }
});
layout.addComponent(label);
```

Then you can add more features to this component, like borders to the label, better icon than the letter x, no borders to the button, transitions etc. etc.

All the code was written directly into StackOverflow and needs to be error checked and properly implemented.